# Rerendering with react-testing-library is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

This is my test

```
    it('should run', async () => {
        const { container } = renderWithContainers(<Wrapper  />)

        window.innerHeight = 50
        await wait(() => fireEvent(window, new Event('resize')))

        expect(getByTestId(container, 'myComponent')).toHaveStyle(`position: relative`)
    })
```

This fails because the original position is `fixed` and im clearly using the `container` defined before the resize event fires...so how can I get it to "rerender" to use the updated container?
in my code once it rerenders it then has a different position (just not in the test)

I've done this:

```
const { container, rerender } = renderWithContainers(<Wrapper  />)
window.innerHeight = 50
await wait(() => fireEvent(window, new Event('resize')))

rerender(<Wrapper />
```

but this breaks with `invariant Violation: Could not find "store" react testing library` but I have wrapped up all that store/provider logic inside `renderWithContainers` so how do I reuse that?

I want to do something like this: `rerender(renderWithContainers(<Wrapper />))` but clearly that wont work

just to be ultra clear, I want to rerender my component after event listener has fired so I can see the updated component

Comment: Hi do you still need an answer for this ?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you can help @KonstanitnosSchoinas!

Comment: renderWithContainers, may contain context providers, you should include those as well. In short copy all code inside renderWithContainers's render(CONTENT), and paste it in rerender(CONTENT).